# How to fetch API key when it is a part of the request headers

Tags: node.js, http-headers, httprequest, response

I have endpoints to a site, e.g '[click here](https://prod.jdgroupmesh.cloud/stores/footpatrol/snippets/iphone-app?expand=content)', I have also sniffed the API token needed and the auth value to view it.

As shown, I want to find out the API token without having to manually enter it in using a request. How would I got about doing this? P.S There is literally no other response headers that give this API, yet all requests need it to be successfully executed.

Comment: The API tokens are part of the site's security mechanism. How to use those vary based on what kind of technique is being used on the server side. Some sites that want others to use their APIs disclose the documentation. Thats the only legal/moral way to find those. For sites like facebook, you just have to register your app with them and they give you API key. Some sites ask for Oauth, some just ask for you to include the key as URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The API tokens are part of the site's security mechanism. How to use those vary based on what kind of technique is being used on the server side. Some sites that want others to use their APIs disclose the documentation.

Thats the only legal/moral way to find those. For sites like facebook, you just have to register your app with them and they give you API key. Some sites ask for OAuth, some just ask for you to include the key as URL parameter.

So the legal/moral way would be to ask them how you can access their APIs.

Comment: Is there a particular place where sites tend to store their api tokens / auth keys, or is this relayed onto a user the first request they make on an application?

Comment: The sites that want to disclose these things have developer sections. 
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html https://developers.facebook.com/docs