# JSON Parsed into object, how to de-construct? [nodeJS]

Tags: json, node.js, body-parser, jsonparser

I have used the following function on a response/body:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(body)
```

When logging it, I want to get for `mainImage`, a key that holds values I want, in the form of:

```
"mainImage":{
        "original":"https://mesh-uploads-legacy.s3.amazonaws.com/mesh-control/2439898fa4b94968afb957162735394c_BANNERmax1plat.jpg"
     },
```

However, instead, I get:

```
 mainImage: [Object],
```

How can I open up the [Object] for every key of mainImage to extract the value of the sub key `original`?

Comment: try logging `parsed.mainImage.original`

Comment: Are you using `console.log` or something else?

Comment: pretty print the object using console.log(JSON.stringify(mainImageObject, null, 2)). You will get to see the entire object pretty printed on the console.

Comment: What output are you getting on `parsed.mainImage.original`

Comment: @DushyantBangal nothing logs

Comment: what about `parsed.mainImage`

Comment: @BalaAbhinav Nothing logs;where do I call the var parsed in that line of code?

Comment: @DushyantBangal `undefined` for parsed.mainImage

Comment: Looks like its not being parsed properly. Post the whole json that you are using for parsing. Where are you getting it from? It might already be parsed

Comment: `parsed.products[0].mainImage` should give you the value for the first product. Its just the logger skipping nested objects, the data is still tehre

Comment: @DushyantBangal could you look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236251/how-to-fetch-api-key-when-it-is-a-part-of-the-request-headers-javascript-nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have posted, it looks like `mainImage` itself is a part of another object.

In this case of deeper nested objects, loggers just fire `.toString()` of all the values, which results in `[Object]` for Objects.

However, this is just in the logger's output. you can still access your values by:

```
parsed.products[x].mainImage
```

where, `x` is the position in array

Comment: Just did a for loop and found all main image. original values. Thanks a lot.~